# Corner of the room is a little bit lighter and shinier

Tags: modeling, rendering, texturing, eevee-render-engine

I am making my first scene in blender and I can’t figure out the render setting of EEVEE.

The main issue I can see in my render is in the corner of the room, where the corner gets little bit lighter and shinier. How can I fix that? Any other tips on improving my render would be very much appreciated.

Picture of my render settings and wall material.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Geometry issue, maybe. Can you add a wireframe screenshot?

Comment: Yes! I added the wireframe i the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your shader setup the Image Texture nodes for the `Normal Map` and the `Bump Map` should have the **Colorspace** set to `Non-Color`, not to Filmic Log.

The Eevee settings look good. Maybe activate `Contact Shadow` in the settings of the light if you haven't yet.

To make the scene more "real" play with the lights. Where comes the light from? Is there a window? Is it dark outside and there is a table lamp? Try an HDRI for the world background.

Make the car metallic and reduce the Roughness value. If the table and books have no Roughness maps then you can add a Noise Texture node with high scaling to the Roughness. This will make them look less "clean" and "flat" (It's hard to tell from the screenshots if you have already done this)

Comment: I have contact shadows on in all the lights. It is meant to be a basement and a dark room without windows. None of that solves my problem of lighter corners but the noise texture made the table look little bit better thanks!